# How to do mocking/monkey patching in huey tasks?

Tags: python, python-mock, python-huey

I want to test a [huey](https://github.com/coleifer/huey) task, and need to patch `requests.get`.

```
# huey_tasks.py

from huey import RedisHuey

huey = RedisHuey()

@huey.task()
def function():
    import requests
    print(requests.get('http://www.google.com'))
```

File that runs tests:

```
import huey_tasks

@patch('requests.get')
def call_patched(fake_get):
    fake_get.return_value = '1'
    huey_tasks.function()
```

Launch huey_consumer: `huey_tasks.huey -w 10 -l logs/huey.log`
Run test, however patching didn't have any effect.

```
[2016-01-24 17:01:12,053] INFO:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Worker-1:Starting new HTTP connection (1): www.google.com
[2016-01-24 17:01:12,562] INFO:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Worker-1:Starting new HTTP connection (1): www.google.com.sg
<Response[200]>
```

If I remove the `@huey.task()` decorator, patching works and `1` gets printed.

So how should I test huey tasks? After all, I can't remove the decorator every time, has to be a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, finally found a way to test

```
# huey_tasks.py

def _function():
    import requests
    print(requests.get('http://www.google.com'))

function = huey.task()(_function)
import huey_tasks
```

The important part is to define actual task function first then decorate it. Note that `huey.task` is a decorator that needs arguments.

```
@patch('requests.get')
def test_patched(fake_get):
    fake_get.return_value = '1'
    huey_tasks._function()
```

Directly run test code without launching `huey_consumer`.

Comment: if you set huey to immediate mode, all tasks will be executed synchronously without a separate worker process. Setting debug=True in the huey settings will also invoke immediate mode.

Answer (score 0):

If I read correctly this is your problem

- Huey tasks run in a separate consumer process
- Unit tests run in their own process

Process cannot mock or patch another. Either

- Make your code paths so that you do not need to mock patch consumer process... don't call tasks directly, but make them functions which you can expose and patch
- Run huey inside your test process using threading